# Facebook App Invites FBSDKAppInviteDialog not appearing for test users on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, facebook

I have implemented Facebook's new 4.0 SDK App Invites Dialog for iOS as per: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios

I am testing it out in the simulator.

When I login with my real Facebook account the App Invite dialog appears and I see all of my friends.  To test the notifications though I want to use facebook test users as this is what the guide recommends:

> We have internal logic that determines whether a push notification is sent to the client. If we detect that the person has installed the app, we may not trigger a push notification. The best way to test push notifications is to use [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users).

However, when I login as a test user for my app and try to bring up the dialog it fails with the following error:

```
Error in invite Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 2.)" UserInfo=0x7f989d8cbe00 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid method_results., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=method_results}
```

If I try with the same test user on the actual phone it works fine.  It seems this issue only occurs on the simulator.

Updated to add the code I'm using:

```
    var inviteDialog : FBSDKAppInviteDialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
    if (inviteDialog.canShow()) {
        let appLinkUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://fb.me/1616988365211522")!
        let previewImageUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Polistes_May_2013-2.jpg")!

        var inviteContent : FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
        inviteContent.previewImageURL = previewImageUrl
        inviteContent.appLinkURL = appLinkUrl
        inviteDialog.content = inviteContent

        inviteDialog.delegate = self
        inviteDialog.show()
    }
```

elsewhere....

```
func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    // nothing to do here
    println("Completed App Invite with results: \(results)")
}

func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    // don't know enough about the errors to let the user know
    println("Error in App Invite: \(error)")
}
```

Note, this is a test version of my app.  The Apple App Store id is not my app (obviously) but since my app is not yet on the store I needed to add something for testing.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full code sample and App Link URL you're using. I've tested this myself and works as expected.

Comment: @corvuszero I am getting friendlist in simulator and after selecting a friend I see the process of invite sending completion but my friend didn't get any notification on his Facebook account.What could be the issue?Under development apps dosen't get the notifications?

Comment: @corvuszero  I added the code I'm using and the app link url I'm using for testing.

Comment: @jeffjv can you update to the latest SDK version and tell me if this fixes your issue? In latest you don't have to call canShow, as it will autodetect and open in safari. Also tested and works as expected.

Comment: same here, app invites works fine with real people (they even receive the notification) but test users I get a "dialog_disabled" error, after briefly seeing the safari open Facebook etc...

Comment: @JakeArmstrong, right.  Facebook engineers are clearly not testing this scenario.  I'm guessing they never tried the combo of test users and web view of Facebook which is odd because that's what anybody using the simulator would do.  Well, not really that odd given the jumbled mess their docs are.  :)

Comment: @jeffjv, they release a lot etc, may be related. It works on a physical device though, with test users. The problem is with the simulator scenario.

Answer (score 0):

i have encountered the same issue ,in my case when i was testing app invite , it was working fine for all user except for one , and the error was:
Printing description of error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 2.)" UserInfo=...     {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=method_results,  com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid method_results.}
```

and this error was occurring for the user whose account i created on Facebook but didn't confirm that account from email link ,after confirming the account this error didn't appeared and i was able to send invite from that particular user.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should upgrade Facebook SDK version
2. Look again at your app's page in Facebook Developer dashboard and check if every required field has a valid value.
3. Test on real device and look if there is any difference in Facebook SDK response.